# TextWatcher not working on multiple TextEdit fields

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

Ok, I was able do auto populate 3 fields with one field with TextWatcher, but I would get an error if I tried to backspace the number and replace it with another, I cannot seem to get the TextWatcher to watch the other fields

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIn);
    final EditText editFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFt);
    final EditText editYd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editYd);

    editIn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)                                                      
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            double in = Double.valueOf(editIn.getText().toString());
            double ft = in / 12;
            double yd = in / 36;
            editFt.setText(String.valueOf(ft));
            editYd.setText(String.valueOf(yd));

            editFt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int  i3) {      
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    double ft = Double.valueOf(editFt.getText().toString());
                    double in = ft * 12;
                    double yd = ft / 3;
                    editIn.setText(String.valueOf(in));
                    editYd.setText(String.valueOf(yd));

                    editYd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int                                        i2, int i3) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                            double yd = Double.valueOf(editYd.getText().toString());
                            double in = yd * 36;
                            double ft = yd * 3;
                            editIn.setText(S`enter code here`tring.valueOf(in));
                            editFt.setText(String.valueOf(ft));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using this

```
double ft = Double.valueOf(editFt.getText().toString());
```

But when there is No text in TextField it will try to do the above stuff which is don't allowed as it'll generate exception.

1. Surround your Code with `try catch` block to handle exception.
2. You can put condition like this

   if(lengthofText!=0)
   {
   //Then do your stuff
   }
   else{
   //Nothing
   }

Comment: Thank you very much TAsk, I did simply surround the code with the try catch without if or else and it works perfectly that way when I enter inches, the feet and yards convert, and I can backspace without crashing! The next problem that I'm having is how to setTextChangedListener on the other 2 fields in order to enter feet and the inches and yards convert automatically...